# Second Order Initial Value problem Query

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Hey guys just wondering for Second Order IVP's how to solve the equation when the root is complex for example:

> Solve the IVP: $$ y'' +9y=0, \space y(0)=1, \space y'(0)=1$$
>   $$ r^2 +9=0$$
>   $$ r^2 =-9$$
>   $$ r = \pm3i$$
>
> I'm unsure what to do now I've found the roots.

I'd appreciate any guidance here.

Comment: These make the solution $y_g=C_1e^{+3ix}+C_2e^{-3ix}$ and after simplifying give $y_g=C_1\sin3x+C_2\cos3x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said the user in the comment the solution is $$y_g(x)=C_1e^{+3ix}+C_2e^{-3ix}$$(see the form of general solution in your book about this kind of ordinary differential equation). Then using $e^{iax}=\cos(ax)+i\sin(ax)$ and that the cosine is even and the sine function an odd function one has $$y_g(x)=C_1(\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x))+C_2(\cos(3x)-i\sin(3x))$$ that is

$$y_g(x)=(C_1+C_2)\cos(3x)+(C_1-C_2)i\sin(3x)$$ thus  $$y'_g(x)=-3(C_1+C_2)\sin(3x)+3(C_1-C_2)i\cos(3x).$$

From your conditions you get (if there are no mistakes in my calculations) $$1=y_g(0)=(C_1+C_2)\cdot 1+0=C_1+C_2$$ and $$1=y'_g(0)=0+3(C_1-C_2)\cdot 1=3C_1-3C_2,$$ thus $C_1=2/3$ and $C_2=1/3$.

Comment: I hope that there are no mistakes, and your dog is very pretty. You can find a lot of examples here in MSE or from Internet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and compliment, both are much appreciated :)